# Roll back in c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have 2 tables enquiry and details.
On save button click I have written

```
fbsave();
fbsavedetails();
```

`fbsave()` save the data in enquiry table and `fbsavedetails()` saves data in details table.

**now if error occur in fbsavedetails() then both steps should be rollback.**

is it possible?

Comment: MS Access or SQL Server?

Comment: how do you do your data layer? stored-procedures? linq-to-sql? connected? disconnected?

Comment: You can do what you want by using transactions, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Of course, it is possible. Could you please provide a skeleton of these two methods and what calls then please?

Comment: You can use `SqlTransaction` class object and bind it with `SqlCommand` object...

Comment: i am using disconnected architecture

Comment: "disconnected architecture" - can you be more specific please? that is very vague, ambiguous and overloaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can explicitly create a transaction and pass that around, i.e.

```
using(var connection = ...)
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var tran = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            FBSave(connection, tran);
            FBSaveDetails(connection, tran);
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that here you **must** also set the `Transaction` on each command, hence why you need to pass it in, and all the commands must be on the same connection object.

---

Or: you can use `TransactionScope`; it is important that the `Open()` happens *inside* the `TransactionScope` to get automatic enlistment:

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
{
    FBSave();
    FBSaveDetails();
    tran.Complete();
}
```

or:

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope())
using(var connection = ...)
{
    connection.Open();
    FBSave(connection);
    FBSaveDetails(connection);
    tran.Complete();
}
```

with the `TransactionScope` approach, you don't need to set anything special - most of it is automatic. You can of course optionally pass the connection into the methods, but they could also obtain their own connection, and in most cases it would work fine.

Comment: Does the "open inside TransactionScope to get automatic enlistment" negate the need for DTC?

Comment: @MrMoose no, but you *can* usually avoid the need for DTC simply by passing the connection around: if you only use one connection object inside the `TransactionScope`, then it gets handled by the LTM rather than DTC (in all versions of SQL Server >= 2005, IIRC)

Answer (score 7):

You can use TransactionScope.

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   //Complete the transaction only when both inserts succeed. 
   scope.Complete();
}
```

if you don't complete the transactionscope it will be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to solve this problem

1. use DbTransaction and pass the DbTransaction around the two method, commit the transaction if success and rollback if error happened
   cons: DbTransaction need to be passed around.
2. use TransactionScope
   pros: ease to use
   cons: Access is not supported, and if the database is sql2000, msdtc is required to be configured