# The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following code that uses `transactionScope`

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    MamConfiguration oldConfiguration;
    int oldTestId;
    using (mamdbEntities = new MaMDBEntities())
    {
        oldConfiguration = GetOldTestId(item.TestID);
        if (oldConfiguration == null)
        {
            ...

            ConvertToEfAndSave(item, oldTestId, oldConfiguration.CreatedDate);
            if(!item.UserMessage.IsErrorOccur)
            {
                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
```

The transaction fails with the following error:

```
17 Feb 2013 09:34:01,359||[15]||ERROR||MamInfrastructure.Logger.Log4NetLogger||Faild Update configuration to DB
System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B)
   at System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32 propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier, Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel& isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[] propagationToken)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.MamConfigurationBlDal.DeleteOldConfigurationTestId(Int32 testId) in d:\Builds\TFS\10\281\Sources\Server\MamAdmin\Dev\Admin 1.5\MaMDBEntityFramework\MamConfigurationBlDal.cs:line 135
   at Conduit.Mam.MaMDBEntityFramework.MamConfigurationBlDal.Save(MamConfigurationBL item) in d:\Builds\TFS\10\281\Sources\Server\MamAdmin\Dev\Admin 1.5\MaMDBEntityFramework\MamConfigurationBlDal.cs:line 77
   at Conduit.Mam.BL.SaveTestToDB.UpdateConfiguration(ABTest configuration, Boolean isProduction, Int32 testID) in d:\Builds\TFS\10\281\Sources\Server\MamAdmin\Dev\Admin 1.5\MaMBL\SaveTestToDB.cs:line 70
   at Conduit.Mam.Admin.Controllers.HomeController.Update(String expression, Boolean isProductionMode, Int32 testId) in d:\Builds\TFS\10\281\Sources\Server\MamAdmin\Dev\Admin 1.5\MAMAdmin\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 114
```

How can it be a `MSDTC`? My transaction isn't distributed

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I always had issues with TransactionScope and the DTC. I asked about this on another question and had [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947274/roll-back-in-c-sharp/13947336#comment19233956_13947336) to my question. Are you using more than one connection object?

Comment: fyi, i removed the t-sql tag, since it is no t-sql related post

Comment: Reformatting your code fragment, shows that you omitted the rest of the `TransactionScope` content (or missed the closing braces). Anyway, note that one reason a transaction will be propagated to a distributed one is, when there are two connections (even to the same datasource) within a scope.

Comment: Elad, Did u get any solution of the above asked question