# transaction locks in MySqlHelper class

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, c#-4.0

i'm going to call mysql Db within my .net code and for that i'm using `MySql.Data.dll`. in my scenario i used `MySqlHelper`class. but in this scenario there are two insert statement and i want to `commit` records if only both are inserted correctly. otherwise i want to `rollback` it.

```
    internal bool AddCutomer(Customer c)
        {
            string sqlCustomerQuery = "INSERT INTO tab_customer VALUES('" + c.Barcode + "','" + c.custxml + "')";
            int result = MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, sqlCustomerQuery);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                string sqlProjCustomer = "INSERT INTO tab_project_customers VALUES('" + c.Barcode + "','" + c.ProjectID + "')";
                MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connectionString, sqlProjCustomer);

                return true;
            }
            else
            return false;

        }
```

**My Question:**

1. How can i commit or roll back in this scenario?
2. I found that [MySqlTransaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqltransaction) can be used to commit & rollback. If i'm going to use this how can i use it? or is there any other way to do it?
3. When can we use `MySqlHelper` class and difference between traditional method (create connection, command etc) and `MySqlHelper` class method?
4. does `MySqlHelper` helper automatically handles locks?

Comment: make it as a StoredProcedure in MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Transaction Scope in c#.

> [Roll back in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947274/roll-back-in-c-sharp/13947342#13947342)